# jquery/javascript error on submit with select option with a white space

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have this Html form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal buscar_php" method="post" action="" autocomplete="off">
```

Which I automatically submit when I change a select option via jquery:

```
$( 'form.buscar_php' ).on("change", "select", function() {
    $('form.buscar_php').submit();
});
```

My problem is with the select options that have a white space. When I choose one of the options without space (e.g. "Locomoción") it works perfectly. This is my select:

```
<select name="tipo_gasto" class="form-control select" data-style="btn-default">
    <option value="">Todos</option>
    <option value="Materiales menores">Materiales menores</option>
    <option value="Locomoción">Locomoción</option>
    <option value="Colación">Colación</option>
    <option value="Notaría">Notaría</option>
    <option value="Leyes sociales">Leyes sociales</option>
    <option value="Impuesto único">Impuesto único</option>
</select>
```

But when I choose, lets say "Materiales menores" I get this error on Firebug:
`Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: option[value=Materiales menores]` and the form is not submitted.
I've tried to do the same thing via javascript putting onchange submit in the select, but nothing changes. So what is the problem?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Will you be able to replicate it in a snippet or something?

Comment: Version: jQuery v2.1.1

Comment: Looks good for me. Can you try using it in a different jQuery version?

Comment: Is it happening only on Firefox?

Comment: I tried with jQuery 1.8 and 2.1. Works. FF and Crome

Comment: I created a fiddle for your example: https://jsfiddle.net/n2fkmqvb/

Comment: ^ That's wow. `:)` @leguano Did you check FF?

Comment: @PraveenKumar same problem with Chrome.

Comment: @PraveenKumar yes i did. chrom 47 and ff38esr

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me too...

Comment: I change the jquery version, but the problem persists.

Comment: Works for me in FF, Chrome and IE